# Generalization of the Riemann integral to functions on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, equidistribution

I want to do something a bit strange: define the Riemann/Darboux integral for bounded real functions defined on the n-dimensional sphere.

The catch: I *cannot* use Lebesgue integration theory to do this. This is because I want to do something similar to averaging the values of the function over an equidistributed sequence of points, and then claiming the averages tend to the integral as I take more and more points. This idea is true for Riemann-integrable functions (see Theorem 1.1 and Corollary 1.1 in the book Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Kuipers and Niederreiter) but it fails for Lebesgue-integrable functions.

In particular, a Dirichlet-type function (nonzero on a countable dense set and zero elsewhere) cannot be Riemann-integrable for my needs.

So, to avoid reinventing the wheel, I'm looking for a reference where someone went through defining the Riemann or Darboux integral for either a sphere or a more general space. The definition must allow the following theorems:

1. Continuous functions are Riemann-integrable.
2. Riemann-integrable functions are Lebesgue-integrable and the two integrals are the same.

Comment: Isn't such an integral just a plain $n$-dimensional riemann integral with some additional factor of the form $det(M'(t))$? ($M$ is some local embedding of the $n$-dimensional plane onto the $n$-dimensional manifold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in most of books an analysis of functions of several variables. Let me mention [Apostol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201002884), [Bartle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433314), [Marsden & Hofman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716721058) and [Spivak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219).